# How to do a ternary operator in react js

Tags: reactjs

How do you do an if statement in React JSX?

I want to do this in my JSX:

```
if(numberOfItems >= 2) {
  <span>numberOfItems</span>
}
```

But laid out like an Elvis operator

`numberOfItems >= 2 ? /* print out numberItems */ : /* do nothing */`

Thanks

Comment: I was in the middle of answering this for you. But now I can't. So here is the answer. You can't use an if statement inside the JSX. 

The best practice would be to use a ternary statement like this: 

`{numberOfItems >= 2 ? <span>{numberOfItems}</span>} : ''`

Comment: Thanks @waz. For answering the question asked. I really appreciate it.

Comment: or you can do `{numberOfItems >= 2 && <span>{numberOfItems}</span>}` too